# How build personal JFrame from a PNG picture

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, paint

I try to build my personal JFrame from a PNG picture. But there is different behavior between Mac OSX 10.8 and Windows 7. (I have to use JDK 6)

Here is my code :

```
[...]

public Fenetre()
{

    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setUndecorated(true);
    this.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));

    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/Images/frame.png"));     
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    this.setSize(image.getWidth(),image.getHeight());                
    this.setLayout(null);


    panel = new JPanel();
    JButton quit = new JButton("Quitter");
    panel.add(quit);
    Dimension size = panel.getPreferredSize();
    panel.setBounds(67, 45, size.width, size.height);

    this.add(panel);

    this.addMouseListener(this);
    this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    this.setVisible(true);      

}

public void paint(Graphics g) {

    Graphics2D g2 =(Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC)); // SRC_ATOP > Windows
    g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    panel.update(panel.getGraphics());

}

[...]
```

The result on Mac OSX 10.8 (AlphaComposite = SRC) :

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/15/maczr.png/

Then, on Windows 7 (AlphaComposite = SRC_ATOP), at start up and when I move it, I can see :

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/16/windowsqu.jpg/

How do it ?

Comment: What exactly is the question? Those results seem identical to me.

Comment: Really ? On the second picture you can seen that when I move the JFrame the outline of the window is changed...

Comment: The windows are system dependent, im not sure its possible to mitigate this completely.

Comment: It's strange, if I minimize the windows after moving it, and then if I restore it I have the good result.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not honoring the paint chain

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    // You must call super.paint somewhere here...

    Graphics2D g2 =(Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC)); // SRC_ATOP > Windows
    g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    panel.update(panel.getGraphics());

}
```

You should NEVER call `Component#update`.

```
    panel.update(panel.getGraphics());
```

This is called on you behalf by the repaint manager, which calls `paint`.

`paint` calls `paintComponent`, `paintBorder` and `paintChildren` failing to honor the paint chain means that not of these methods are been called and they are very important

As camickr has pointed out, you should never need to overrride the `paint` method of a top level container, like `JFrame`.

Instead, create a custom component that is capable of performing you painting for you and set it as the frames content pane...

```
this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
this.setUndecorated(true);
this.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));

setContentPane(new FancyPaintPane());

pack();
```

And the `FancyPaintPane`

```
public class FancyPaintPane extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage image;

    public FancyPaintPane() {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/Images/frame.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        setOpaque(false);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC)); // SRC_ATOP > Windows
        g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        g2.dispose();
    }
}
```

You should also never modify a `Graphics` context without reverting it.  These are shared resources across all components within the same top level container.  A better approach is to create a copy which you can manipulate and dispose of when you're done...

You are also trying to show a component with transparent elements without first marking the component as transparent.  This can produce nasty paint artifacts.  You should call `JComponent#setOpaque` passing it a `false` value.

I would also strongly discourage you from using `null` layouts.  They have a nasty habit of coming back and biting you.

**Updated with simple example**

[image]

```
public class CirclePaneTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CirclePaneTest();
    }

    public CirclePaneTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }

                CirclePane circlePane = new CirclePane();
                circlePane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                circlePane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                        if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    }
                });

                JLabel label = new JLabel("Look Ma, I'm a circle");
                label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setUndecorated(true);
                frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
                frame.setContentPane(circlePane);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(label);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class CirclePane extends JPanel {

        public CirclePane() {
            setOpaque(false);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected int getRadius() {
            return Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) - 1;
        }

        @Override
        public Insets getInsets() {

            int radius = getRadius();
            int xOffset = (getWidth() - radius) / 2;
            int yOffset = (getHeight() - radius) / 2;
            Insets insets = new Insets(
                    radius / 6,
                    radius / 6,
                    radius / 6,
                    radius / 6);

            return insets;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponent(g);

            int radius = getRadius();
            int xOffset = (getWidth() - radius) / 2;
            int yOffset = (getHeight() - radius) / 2;

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setColor(getBackground());
            g2d.fillOval(xOffset, yOffset, radius, radius);
            g2d.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            g2d.drawOval(xOffset, yOffset, radius, radius);
            g2d.dispose();

        }
    }
}
```

**Updated with code for Java 7**

The following code should be used to set up the frame to be transparent under Java 6.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
frame.setUndecorated(true);
try {
    Class<?> awtUtilsClass = Class.forName("com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities");
    if (awtUtilsClass != null) {

        Method method = awtUtilsClass.getMethod("setWindowOpaque", Window.class, boolean.class);
        method.invoke(null, frame, false);
    }

} catch (Exception exp) {
}
//frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
frame.setContentPane(circlePane);
```

Comment: Thank you for all these recommendations... Really interesting. But I have the same issue...

Comment: Sorry for this missing detail... :)

Comment: I've updated with additional code to show how to make a window transparent under Java 6

Comment: I also have an example to make the content pane semi-transparent and allow you to move the window as well...

Comment: @G.Bach `Rant.init()`, `Rant.start()` ... ;)

Comment: Now, it works... @MadProgrammer thanks a lot for all your recommendations and your help !

Answer (score 5):

Your code is incomplete, but it seems to me like you are overriding the paint() method of a JFrame. You should never do this (unless you know what you doing and you invoke super.paint(..))!

If you want to display an image in the frame then either:

a) add a JLabel with an image to the frame
b) or do custom painting on a JPanel by overriding the paintComponent() method and then add the panel to the frame.

Comment: I don't want display an image in the frame, I want build the frame with my PNG picture...

Comment: I don't understand the difference between those two.

Comment: I want have a window without the default border but with the "shadow" of my picture.

Comment: @user2038175 And how do you suppose that is achieved, by displaying your image with in paintable context where the frame would have been...setting the frame's content pane would be a easier method...